# building apk of an android project via command line fails after including some library projects

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, eclipse-adt

Building the apk for my project fails because ant is searching for the build.xml for the library nineoldandroid.

here's the shell script http://pastebin.com/fhcj9GKG

Tried finding for a way to create build.xml for the library project but failed.
I also tried ant clean, android update and also tried doing it on both windows and linux, computer restart,update adt and other methods but failed to fix the problem. This error appeared after including library projects on my main project.

note : im using adt's ant, i also tried building it without running adt just in case there is a conflict when using ant by two processes but same error appears.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

[image: Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create the missing build.xml:

```
cd /home/jisidro/ws/temp/NineOldAndroid/
path/to/sdk/tools/android update project --path /home/jisidro/ws/temp/NineOldAndroid/ --subprojects
```

Comment: thanks! it worked :D im encountering googleplayservices error but the initial error is now gone thank you!